# Dependant dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, html, drop-down-menu

I have created a dependant dropdown list using this code:

**PHP**

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <select class="form-control" name="select1" id="select1">
   <option value="1">Fruit</option>
   <option value="2">Animal</option>
   <option value="3">Bird</option>
   <option value="4">Car</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <select class="form-control" name="select2" id="select2">
   <option value="1">Banana</option>
   <option value="1">Apple</option>
   <option value="1">Orange</option>
   <option value="2">Wolf</option>
   <option value="2">Fox</option>
   <option value="2">Bear</option>
   <option value="3">Eagle</option>
   <option value="3">Hawk</option>
   <option value="4">BWM<option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**Index.js**

```
var $select1 = $( '#select1' ),
    $select2 = $( '#select2' ),
$options = $select2.find( 'option' );

$select1.on( 'change', function() {
     $select2.html( $options.filter( '[value="' + this.value + '"]' ) );
} ).trigger( 'change' );
```

Now I want to retrieve the text value between the   tag and not just the value.

So I modified the value like (**for all the options**):

```
 <option value="1|Fruit">Fruit</option>
```

I will retrieve it using:

```
 $test1 = explode('|', $_POST['select1']);
 $test2 = explode('|', $_POST['select2']);
```

But obviously after using this my script won't trigger the change for select2.

What changes should I make to the index.js to make it work with the above change? I'm stuck here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split()` function to seperate numbers from the `value` of `#select1` options.

Check if the `value` starts with that number in `#select2`([attribute^=value](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp))

```js
var $select1 = $( '#select1' ),
$select2 = $( '#select2' ),
$options = $select2.find( 'option' );

$select1.on( 'change', function() {
 $select2.html( $options.filter( '[value^="' + (this.value).split("|")[0] + '"]' ) );
} ).trigger( 'change' );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <select class="form-control" name="select1" id="select1">
   <option value="1|Fruit">Fruit</option>
   <option value="2|Animal">Animal</option>
   <option value="3|Bird">Bird</option>
   <option value="4|Car">Car</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <select class="form-control" name="select2" id="select2">
   <option value="1|Banana">Banana</option>
   <option value="1|Apple">Apple</option>
   <option value="1|Orange">Orange</option>
   <option value="2|Wolf">Wolf</option>
   <option value="2|Fox">Fox</option>
   <option value="2|Bear">Bear</option>
   <option value="3|Eagle">Eagle</option>
   <option value="3|Hawk">Hawk</option>
   <option value="4|BMW">BWM<option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. I have changed the values for select2 also. <option value="1|Banana">Banana</option>

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response!

Answer (score 1):

First thing I noticed was the $'s in the variable names in your JS

Change the

```
var $select1 = $( '#select1' ),
$select2 = $( '#select2' ),
```

to

```
var select1 = $( '#select1' ),
select2 = $( '#select2' ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you only want the options to show up which belong to the parent.

You might want to consider giving `select2` a `data-{name}` attribute, like `data-parent`. After that you can use `getAttribute()` to see which was the parent option in `select1`.

But probably even better, you can create 3 separate selects and have them show up or hide whenever a certain parent option is selected. Don't give them the same `id` or `name` attribute though. Because they are not displayed doesn't mean they don't exist. Their IDs cause problems it they are the same and similars thing will go wrong when the select data is sent.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the best way because it will cause a lot of data duplication for me

Comment: Are you sure, because every option in `select1` gets a separate select containing only the available options which belong to that particular parent (in this case each 3 options). But I might not understand what you're trying to achieve. You could than still use the first option with `getAttribute()`